# Which version of ubuntu uses kernel 2.6.30.10

Tags: kernel

Hi, I need an ISO image of Ubuntu which uses kernel 2.6.30.10., where it would be available?

Please could you provide me with a link?

*I would like  to do few experiments with it.*

Answer (score 3):

Here it goes

By default, the 12.04.2 point release will ship with a newer 3.5.0-23.35 Ubuntu kernel from Quantal, and a matching X.org stack.

11.04 has a kernel based on mainline branch stable kernel 2.6.38.2.

10.10 RC includes the 2.6.35-22.33 kernel which is based on the 2.6.35.4 Upstream stable kernel.

So you'll have to go older.  I don't recommend it because all on them with the exception of 10.04LTS, and 12.04LTS are unsupported anymore.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can find ISO images of all the old releases at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases

There is no release with exactly a 2.6.30 kernel. Ubuntu 9.04 uses kernel 2.6.28 and 9.10 kernel 2.6.31 respectively.

As noted, these are unsupported releases which probably contain unpatched security flaws.